# What is the difference between show on timeline and allow on timeline in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I notice some posts on my Facebook Timeline have options for "Show on Timeline" and "Allow on Timeline" but I couldn't find what is the difference between them.

The post that has these options was posted from the Run Keeper app. It might be only for app generated post, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Show on Timeline` forces the Activity to be shown on the timeline

`Allow on Timeline` just enables posting of that activity to timeline, it still *may or may not* end up on your timeline...the power to whether show or not resides with Facebook's feed algorithms

you can always watch over `https://facebook.com/{your username}/allactivity` to toggle show/allow and also look over what the information apps are logging onto facebook